# Using Python to Read Non-Strict CSV File

Tags: python, csv

My CSV file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/st7qxj93cp0imhr/test.csv)

Here is my data format:

> 1763212493,zhangniuzhang,male,,yes，(this is chinese comma,not in english)i
>   do,hubei  wuhan,1763212493,69,86,316,,,tp2.sinaimg.cn/1763212493/50/5613831962/1,0,"free,house,trip,80","1863415082,1752861352"

and my code :

```
import csv

with open("test.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

It's very simple, but I got like following:

```
{'mn': '316', 'ci': '', 'sx': 'male', 'ei': '', 'ad': 'hubei;"wuhan', 'vi': '', 'fui;': 'house', 'de': 'yes\xef\xbc\x8ci do', 'iu': 'tp2.sinaimg.cn/1763212493/50/5613831962/1', 'an': '69', 'un': '1763212493', 'iv': '0', 'sn': 'zhangniuzhang', None: ['trip', '80""', '1863415082', '1752861352"""'], 'tg': 'free', '_id': '1763212493', 'fn': '86'}
{'mn': '1104', 'ci': '', 'sx': 'femail', 'ei': '', 'ad': 'jilin;"changchun', 'vi': '', 'fui;': 'art', 'de': '', 'iu': 'tp2.sinaimg.cn/1854635021/50/1289455604/0', 'an': '71', 'un': '1854635021', 'iv': '0', 'sn': 'ladywang', None: ['reading', 'music""', '1949520584', '1288127940', '1193111400"""'], 'tg': 'life', '_id': '1854635021', 'fn': '258'}
```

For the first record, `ad` equals `hubei;"wuhan`, but in the original file there is no `"`; it is in a different column.

Many fields have wrong value. For the first record:

> 1763212493,zhangniuzhang,male,,yes，i
>   do,hubei  wuhan,1763212493,69,86,316,,,tp2.sinaimg.cn/1763212493/50/5613831962/1,0,"free,house,trip,80","1863415082,1752861352"

The output should be:

```
{'mn': '316', 'ci': '', 'sx': 'male', 'ei': '', 'ad': 'hubei wuhan', 'vi': '', 'fui': '1863415082,1752861352', 'de': 'yes\xef\xbc\x8ci do', 'iu': 'tp2.sinaimg.cn/1763212493/50/5613831962/1', 'an': '69', 'un': '1763212493', 'iv': '0', 'sn': 'zhangniuzhang', 'tg': 'free,house,trip,80', '_id': '1763212493', 'fn': '86'}
```

But the output is mess, not the right order nor the right values.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like .

filepath is the path of your  test.csv

```
fdata = open(filepath) 
fread = [ l for l in fdata.readlines() if l.strip() ]
```

now you can iterate fread

Comment: with open("test.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = [l for l in f.readlines() ]
    for row in reader:
        print row

Comment: the result is same:1763212493,zhangniuzhang,male,,yes，i do,hubei;"wuhan,1763212493,69,86,316,,,tp2.sinaimg.cn/1763212493/50/5613831962/1,0,""free,house,trip,80"",""1863415082,1752861352"""

1854635021,ladywang,femail,,,jilin;"changchun,1854635021,71,258,1104,,,tp2.sinaimg.cn/1854635021/50/1289455604/0,0,""life,art,reading,music"",""1949520584,1288127940,1193111400"""